# 2 icon for the same application in springBoard with ADHoc

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

i have a weird bug with my application.

My app is a 'white label' app and i use allot of bundle IDs (and certification for push ..), i use the adHoc distribution to let testers install it. (i host my app in my server, not testFlight for example).

The problem (in iOS 6 and 7 ) is that when the app is almost installed, a new icon is displayed (and i can use it to launch the app) and the old one remain with statue = "installation .."

Can you help to solve this, thanks.

[image: demo]

Comment: i already explain this on my comment, but thanks for replaying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is created because of the `bundle-identifier` unmatched in your app's plist and .ipa.

Please make sure that the bundle identifiers match when you make the build.

We also had this problem and now we have resolved it. 
[image]

Comment: You was faster them me to post the answer :) this was the problem. (in 24 hours you will get the 50 points ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Please delete both the apps (the new one and one with installation), then try once again.

I think this is the problem of same provisioning profile used for both the apps.

Comment: I do't think so if two apps have same app id then second one will surely overwrite last build.

Comment: It will replace only if you are using different version of the same application..

Comment: i test this, and this is reproduced in allot of devices.